# Need to extract Page ID from source using selenium

Tags: regex, selenium

```
<table width="100%" id="sfc">
<caption>Self Help Center</caption>
<tr><td valign="top">
<tr>
<td width="100%" valign="top">
<a href="http://supportsolutions.ds.adp.com/external/SOAP/webSuite2DealerSuiteLogon.asp? cnumber=C149491&page=doc&PageID=4f052a6906229_TOM" target="_blank" title="Online User Guides" >Online Documentation</a>
</td></tr></table>
```

I need to extract href value.

Comment: Figure Out answer of this: 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("OnlineDocumentation"));
String thisLink = element.getAttribute("href");

Answer (score 0):

or:

```
open | file:///C:/Users/x/Desktop/page.html

storeHtmlSource | source

store | 0 | delimiter0

store | 1 | delimiter1

store | javascript{storedVars['source'].split('href="')[storedVars['delimiter1']]} | href0

store | javascript{storedVars['href0'].split('\"')[storedVars['delimiter0']]} | href1
```